# How to make this the sample SQL Atomic?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an store procedure,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertDealGallery] 
(
    @ImageID INT,
    @DealID INT
)
AS

    DECLARE @MaxOrder INT;
    SELECT @MaxOrder = MAX([Order]) + 1 FROM DealGallery WHERE DealID = @DealID

    IF (@MaxOrder IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @MaxOrder = 1;
    END



   INSERT INTO [DealGallery]
                ([ImageID]
                ,[DealID]
                ,[Order])  
        VALUES
                (@ImageID
                ,@DealID
                ,@MaxOrder)
```

But I am fearing that this is not atomic because in the same time MaxOrder might remain same in concurrent thread. SO how to make this atomic?

Comment: What you're basically doing here is manually calculating an integer identity field.

Comment: @STLDeveloper, Yes. I need to make this atomic

Comment: Any reason you can't just store the time the record was added to control the order? Seems like it would be functionally equivalent to what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertDealGallery] 
(
    @ImageID INT,
    @DealID INT
)
AS BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.DealGallery (ImageID, DealID, [Order])  
    SELECT 
          @ImageID
        , @DealID
        , ISNULL(MAX(d.[Order]) + 1, 1)
    FROM (SELECT a = 1) t
    LEFT JOIN dbo.DealGallery d ON d.DealID = @DealID

END
```

Or try this one -

```
INSERT INTO dbo.DealGallery (ImageID, DealID, [Order])  
    SELECT 
          @ImageID
        , @DealID
        , ISNULL(m, a)
    FROM (SELECT a = 1) t
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT m = MAX(d.[Order]) + 1
        FROM dbo.DealGallery d 
        WHERE d.DealID = @DealID
    ) t2 ON 1 = 1
```

Comment: Getting error `The correlation name 't' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause.`

Comment: I will test and let u know?

Comment: Ok. After testing, please, tell about your results.

Comment: You need to change the ISOLATION LEVEL; this is not concurrent-safe as written.

Answer (score 3):

Transactions is the feature to obtain atomic behavior. You know that a from ACID is for Atomic.
But you have choiced a very bad design, the aggegration function can lock all rows, performance becomes very poor.

**Edited**

You should move to identitat data type. Also another techniques exists, like counter table, but easy way is identity.

To enclose code into a transaction you should to include 'Begin transaction' and 'commit' sentences.

**Edited 2**

This approach, with a counter for each `Deal`, will avoid lock all `DealGallery`'s rows, only lock `DealGalleryCounter` row.

```
CREATE TABLE DealGalleryCounter 
  (DealID INT not null primary key,
   order int default 0
  );   -- Or add column to an existing deal table. 

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertDealGallery] 
(
    @ImageID INT,
    @DealID INT
)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @order int

    begin transaction
    set transaction isolation level serializable
    -- repeatable read is enough --

    select @order = order + 1
      from DealGalleryCounter 
     where @DealID = DealID

    if @order is null
      insert into DealGalleryCounter (DealID) values (@DealID)

    INSERT INTO dbo.DealGallery (ImageID, DealID, [Order])  
    VALUES ( @ImageID, @DealID, @order );

    update DealGallery 
       set DealGalleryCounter = @order
     where @DealID = DealID;

    commit;    --or check for errors and rollback
END
```

Comment: I have included more comments in answer.

Comment: The problem is that order-range is seprate fro each deal. So, deal = 1 order = 1,2,3,4 and deal 2 = 1,2,3,4

Comment: Add a counter field in deal.

Comment: How? I am not aware about counter field which depend upon an ID

Comment: Posted, see it and come back.

Comment: Thanks. It looks little complex. I am checking Devart suggestion. If Devart suggestion n not work I will try your suggestion. Thanks agian

Comment: Issue is not SQL syntax, is performance. For few data you should use @devart approach.

Answer (score 0):

This should work: insert max order increased by one when deal id is found in DealGallery table otherwise insert max order as 0

```
BEGIN TRAN

  INSERT INTO [DealGallery]
                  ([ImageID]
                  ,[DealID]
                  ,[Order])
  SELECT @ImageID, @DealID, MAX([Order]) + 1
  FROM DealGallery WHERE DealID = @DealID
  UNION
  SELECT @ImageID, @DeadID, 1
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS C) AS T
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DealGallery WHERE DealID = @DealID)

COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: Is Transaction is required?

Comment: You need to change the ISOLATION LEVEL; this is not concurrent-safe as written.